# dyld API on iPhone - strange output

Tags: ios, c, jailbreak, dyld

I have three question for you, all related to dyld :)

I have been using [this dyld man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/dyld.3.html) as a basis. I have compiled the following code and successfully executed the binary on my jailbroken device.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mach-o/dyld.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
   uint32_t image_count, i;
   image_count = _dyld_image_count();
   for (i = 0; i < image_count; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", _dyld_get_image_name(i));
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I thought that these functions let me find all the shared libraries that are loaded in my program's address-space. On my mac, the output is pretty straightforward: It shows the paths to all the libraries that are currently loaded in memory. On my iPhone the output is nearly the same - i also get filepaths - but there are no files at the specified location. (On my mac on the other hand, i can locate the files!)

This is a sample line from the output: 
    /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib

According to ls, iFile and all the other tools i've used, this directory (/usr/lib/system/) is empty. Why? Where are those files?

Another thing i'd like to know is: Is it possible to locate a library in memory? From what offset to what offset the library is mapped into memory? I think i know how to find the beginning but i have no idea how to find the end of the library. To find the beginning, i'd use the address returned by _dyld_get_image_header - Is that correct?

Last question: I wanted to load a dynamic lib system-wide so i assumed i could use DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES to do just that. However, every binary i try to execute after inserting my lib crashes and produces a bus error! Did i forget something or is it the dynamic library that causes the crash?

Comment: You should add that you are working on a jailbroken device. If you are not working on a jailbroken device, then that is the reasoning for the unexpected behavior as apps are sandboxed and have limited to no access outside of their little sandbox.

Comment: Isn't the library size stored in the header? Else: the specified files are not there because there actually not there! They're stored in the kernel cache but they have their pathname hardcoded into the dylib file, that's why dyld reports them where they are (n't really).

Answer (score 2):

the libraries are located at :
/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.dyld/dyld_shared_cache_armv6 (_armv7)
This is a big file were all the single libraries have been joined into one large one.

See http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileSubstrate for hooking on jailbroken device

Yes one can determine the position of a dylib in memory, even on non jailbroken devices.
parse the LC_SEGMENT(_*TEXT)-Section Header(*_text) of the library then you can get the base address of the library and the size of the TEXT __text segment. Then query for the vmslide. Add this to the base address of the TEXT __text.

A detailed description of the mach-o file format can be found here: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachORuntime/Reference/reference.html. Pay special attention to "segment_command"-structure.